# Bootstrap 3: not all glyphicons content codes are loading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm facing a bit of a strange issue, and I hope someone can help me out.
I am trying to load glyphicons by their content code in a list.

Now, the issue I am facing is the following:
All glyphicon codes who do not start with an 'e' are working like a charm:

```
.contact-box__info--email::before {
    content:"\2709";
}
```

But the glyphicons starting with an 'e' are not working:

```
.contact-box__info--phone::before {
    content: "\e035"; 
}
```

The glyphicons are loaded well in my bootstrap. When I call the glyphicons via a span like so:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
```

They work well..

Basically only these glyphicons are working:

```
.glyphicon-asterisk:before {
  content: "\2a";
}

.glyphicon-plus:before {
  content: "\2b";
}

.glyphicon-euro:before {
  content: "\20ac";
}

.glyphicon-minus:before {
  content: "\2212";
}

.glyphicon-cloud:before {
  content: "\2601";
}

.glyphicon-envelope:before {
  content: "\2709";
}

.glyphicon-pencil:before {
  content: "\270f";
}
```

Did someone else faced this issue before?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

In one of our recent project, we also faced similar issue and after some research it was found that one of our front end developer had changed the default bootstrap font-family for @font-face and glyphicon class in bootstrap.css file. 
reverting those to bootstrap default values (`font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';`) 
solved the issue.